# Typescript references wrong type declaration

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my project I'm using 2 external libraries ([G6](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@antv/g6) and [dagre.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dagre)) that themselves or inside dependencies share the same module declaration name `dagre`.
While working on the code and compiling, after

```
import { graphlib } from "dagre";
```

my TypeScript is referencing the wrong one - `dagre-compound` (that is a dep of `@antv/g6`) and not `@types/dagre`.
So I have this error coming out

```
Argument of type '{ width: number; height: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GraphOptions'.
```

The problem started to appear after updating `node` v12->v16 and `TypeScript` v3.9.9 -> v.4.6

Check out the sandbox with reproduction of the issue.

https://codesandbox.io/s/imports-conflict-g6-dagre-pxmy7s

Is there a way to resolve this conflict?

Comment: removing `import G6 from "@antv/g6";` fixes your issue.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Well, I do need import of `@antv/g6` for other functionality that's not included in the reproduction. So it should stay.

Comment: I have no problems on Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-yvuk5w?file=index.ts

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler And that is surprising - I did check there yesterday and didn't run into the issue.
But it is reproduced in my local setup MacOS+nvm(v16)+VSCode+TypeScript(v4.6.0) as well as in CodeSandbox